# How to execute a method at background using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pdf, radpdf

I am using a third party control to load the pdf in it, where the Pdf's are lazy loaded. In my scenario i want to load few pages at page load and want to load rest of the **`pages to load at background.`**

```
// Load the required pages at the Load.
function PreLoadPdf(startpage, endpage) {
    myApi.addEventListener("rendered", function () {
        for (var i = startpage; i <= endpage ; i++) {
            myApi.getPage(i).loadRendered();
        }
    });
}
```

Now above code performs preloading the Pdf's which i want, but also i want to load the remaining page in background. **`How to execute the Jquery Method at the background of the page without freezing the page.`** and also i am not supposed to use,

`setTimeout(function () {}`

Comment: How, actully user does not no about the loading he just view the some pages in the reader while rest of pages should load at background

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to solve this issue, but I believe the best solution would be to use jQuery's `promise` API.

```
//Untested code... typed on the fly
//May have minor syntax errors.

var fileList = [
  "http://example.com/file1.pdf",
  "http://example.com/file2.pdf"
];


var promiseArray = [];

// Fill the file promise array
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var promise = $.get(fileList[i]);
    promiseArray.push(promise);
  });
}

$.when.apply($, promiseArray).then(function() {    
  // All have been resolved (or rejected), do your thing    
});
```